# How can I use a pretrained embedding to gensim skipgram model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, gensim, word2vec

I want to train part of the corpus first and then based on the embeddings train on the whole corpus. Can I achieve this with gensim skipgram?

I haven't found an API that can pass initial embeddings.

what I want is some thing like

```py
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
sentences = [["cat", "say", "meow"], ["dog", "say", "woof"],
             ["cat2", "say2", "meow"], ["dog2", "say", "woof"]]
model = Word2Vec(sentences[:2], min_count=1)
X = #construct a new one
model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1, initial_embedding=X)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this: if you have the whole corpus, and can train on the whole corpus, you're likely to get the best results from whole-corpus training.

And, to the extent there's anything missing from the 2nd-corpus, the 2nd-corpus training will tend to pull vectors for words still training away from words that are no longer in the corpus – causing comparability of vectors within the corpus to decay. (It's only the interleaved tug-of-war between examples including all words that nudges them into positions that are meaningfully related to each other.)

But, keeping that caveat in mind: you can continue to `train()` a model with new data. That is:

```
# initialize & do all default training
model = Word2Vec(sentences[:2], min_count=1)
# now train again even more with a slightly different mix
model.train(sentences, total_examples = len(sentences), epochs=model.epochs)
```

Note in such a case the model's discovered vocabulary is only based on the original initialization. If there are words only in `sentences[0]`, when those sentences are presented to the model that didn't see those words during its initialization, they will be ignored – and never get vectors. (If using your tiny example corpus in this way, the word 'cat' won't get a vector. Again, you really want to train on the largest corpus – or at least use the largest corpus, with a superset of words, 1st.)

Also, a warning will be logged, because the 2nd training will again start the internal `alpha` learning-rate at its larger starting value, then gradually decrease it to the final `min_alpha` value. To be yo-yo'ing the value like this isn't standard SGD, and usually indicates a user error. But, it might be tolerable depending on your goals – you just need to be aware when you're doing unusual training sequences like this, you're off in experimental/advanced land and have to deal with possible side-effects via your own understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Besides, is there any way I can set the initial embedding myself? for example`model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1, initial_embedding=np.ones(n))`

Comment: There's no initialization arg like `initial_embedding`. But, rather than supplying the corpus at model-initialization, you can leave it out, & then do the next required step, `model.build_vocab(corpus)`, explicitly. At that point, the model is initialized with a vocabulary & (meaningfless) internal weights – so you can use normal Python direct tampering with object properties to affect any changes you'd like. Check the property `.wv`, & source code for `keyedvectors.py`, to see relevant properties, especially the `model.wv.vectors` array. After, you'd then need to `model.train(corpus, ...)`.